# How to spy the element twice to cover the code in karma -jasmine

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

ts code:-

```
this.shared.refreshPageObeservable().subscribe(data => {
    if (data && Object.keys(data).length) {
        this.userDetails.fullName = `${data.firstName}  ${data.lastName}`;
        this.userDetails.lastLogin = `${data.lastLoginDt}`;
    } else {
        this.userDetails.fullName = '';
        this.userDetails.lastLogin = '';
    }
});
```

spec file :-

```
spyOn(shared, 'refreshPageObeservable').and.returnValue(of({firstName: 'john', lastName: 'doe', lastLoginDt: '12345'}));

fixture.detectChanges();
```

this code overs the if statement, but how to cover the else part.

Answer (score 0):

Give an empty object so the `Object.keys(data).length` in the if statement is false so it goes to the else block

```
it('should set fullName and lastLogin to an empty string', () => {
  spyOn(shared, 'refreshPageObeservable').and.returnValue(of({}));
  // call the function again that is responsible for subscribing to that stream
  expect(component.userDetails.fullName).toBe('');
  expect(component.userDetails.lastLogin).toBe('');
});
```